# Absence of getting Set-Cookie header with fetch() in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch, expo, response-headers

I'm new to using the Fetch API with React Native and I'm using it for a project of mine. I need the **fetch()** method in order to acquire the **set-cookie header** and get the **PHPSESSID** value. This is the code that I have.

```
fetch("https://fs.auroville.org.in/", {
     credentials: 'include',
     headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     }
})
     .then(request => {
          console.log(request.headers)
          //console.log(get_set_cookies(request.headers))
})
     .catch((error) => {
          console.log("Error")
          console.error(error)
});
```

It seems to work with the code I have but for some reason it seems that the set-cookie header doesn't show up. I know that it only shows up in the network tab in the Google Chrome Inspect Tab  when you first open it but after it doesn't.

[Network Tab When accessing the site for the first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5OvM.png)

I'm wondering if anyone can help as I done a lot of research and I can't seem to find a solid solution to it, even when I call the function for the first time the 'Set-Cookie' header doesn't show but every other header does.

This is the code for the get_set_cookies() function

```
const get_set_cookies = function(headers) {
        const set_cookies = []
        for (const [name, value] of headers) {
                set_cookies.push(value)
        }
        return set_cookies
}
```

Comment: If it's an HTTP-only cookie, JavaScript is not allowed to see the header by design. Also, is this a same-origin or cross-origin request?

Comment: Also, what does `get_set_cookies` do? Want to make sure the issue isn't in how you're reading `request.headers`.

Comment: In terms of the request I believe its a same-origin, removing the credentials and headers property doesn't change the problem, I still get the same output. Also `get_set_cookies` is just a helper function to go through the headers, pick out the cookies and return them

Comment: Can you share that helper function in the question?

Comment: Sure, I edited the orginal post

Comment: Hm, doesn't look like a full function you added. Is `headers` the fetch response headers or something else? Doesn't look like it's doing anything with `set-cookie` specifically.

Comment: Sorry about I didn't look at the function before submitting the edit, I updated it with the whole function

Comment: I wonder if these [known issues with cookie authentication and fetch](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network#known-issues-with-fetch-and-cookie-based-authentication) are relevant here.

Comment: I was thinking of that but aren't I trying to get a cookie, not setting it?